# How can I decode the salt of this argon2i passwordhash?

Tags: password-hashing, argon2

I have this password hash: `$argon2i$v=19$m=128,t=2411,p=2$hmJvvpH3BZlvb2V1vLm/yf3zANU4qNpKuw5TBnGzo2I$<censored>`.

I know the password, and I want to verify if this password will produce the same hash the the above. Using an online argon2 hashing site: https://antelle.net/argon2-browser/

My problem is I don't know how to convert the salt into the right format for hashing.

Comment: The salt is just the "hmJvvpH3BZlvb2V1vLm/yf3zANU4qNpKuw5TBnGzo2I" part, after base64 decoding the (32 byte / 256 bit) binary data. It is between `$` signs that are not in the base64 alphabet (sorry, I wrote "password hash" instead of "salt" before in this comment).